# Can not login as root after installing zsh

Tags: kali-linux, login, authentication, sddm

I installed ZSH and made it the default bash for my kali linux system, then I rebooted the system, and I could not login as root any more. I type in the correct password and it says LOGIN FAILED. I switched to another window by hitting (CTRL+ALT+F1), then I logged in. And viewed the logs of authentication by this command

```bsh
tail /var/log/auth.log
```

And there was a line that says

```
pam_succeed_if(sddm:auth): requirement "user != root" not met by user "root"
```

Any help??!

Comment: "I made zsh the default bash" makes no sense. `bash` is one shell and `zsh` is another.  Also, you haven't said what it is you've actually done. Did you actually _delete_ `bash`?  In this case, I'm not surprised that you hosed your system. If not, and you only changed root's login shell, then change it back. There is seldom if ever any point in changing the root user's login shell, simply because you're not supposed to work in an interactive root shell for very much of the time (if at all; it tends to be a surefire way of hosing the system).

Comment: I ment I changed the default shell to zsh

Comment: It's still not clear what that actually means. Did you replace `bash` with `zsh`, or did you just change root's login shell?

Comment: No, I just changed it by typing `chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh root`

Comment: If I have to guess, you have PAM configured to use [pam_shells](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_shells). Can you add the content of `/etc/pam.d/sddm` and (if it exists) `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the display manager to lightdm worked for me.
I did so by installing lightdm through `apt-get install lightdm`, and then changing to it through `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`